# How can I create a text editor that contains two image?

Tags: android, android-layout

Please see the mock-up below:

[image: Mock-up of control to create]

I would like to create this kind of edit text control with two drawable objects. One image is on the left side just showing a search icon. The other image is on the right side and is lined up with the search icon and search text. The search text editor is between the two images.

How can I go about creating an edit text like in the image above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably create a custom view extending `LinearLayout`. And use some kind of layout like this.

```
 <LinearLayout
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:orientation="horizontal">

     <ImageView/> <!-- For search icon -->

     <EditText/> <!-- with custom background which has alpha 0 -->

     <View/> <!-- for the divider -->

     <ImageView/> <!-- for heart icon -->
</LinearLayout>
```

And my custom class

```
public class CustomEditText extends LinearLayout {

    private EditText editText;
    // Other views if necessary        

    public CustomEditText(Context context) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                   .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_layout,
                   this, true);
        editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.my_edittext_id);
    }

    public String getText() {
        return editText.getText().toString();
    }

 }
```

You can make it more interactive by adding `TextWatcher` and listeners.

Comment: Thanks bro. I tried this way and got the output as per my requirement.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need anything special. Just use a container with three objects:

- The container holds:

  - Search icon image/link
  - Text box
  - (Maybe a in-lined pipe character or image?)
  - Heart icon/link

You may have to play around with the objects to get them to line up correctly but that would be the simplest approach.

I see that there is also a a | (pipe-looking) character/image between the text box and the heart. This may be a fourth object or a part of the heart image. It's up to you.

By the way, if you look around you might find fonts that have heart and "search" icon characters so you would not have to manage images at all. If you use fonts you will simply have a container with two or three labels and one text edit box.

Comment: +1 for your quick reply. I Am a beginner. I don't know much about this concept. so i tried using Froyo answer and got the output.

Comment: Rameshababu, I admit my answer was very high level because there are so many different ways to achieve the design you were looking for. But yes, I agree that @Froyo's answer is concrete and quite good. I up-vote it too.

Answer (score 2):

you can use `android:drawableLeft` and `android:drawableRight` if the pipe and the heart are only one drawable

```
<EditText 
    android:id="@+id/buttonId"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/search"
    android:drawableRight="@drawable/heart"
    android:drawablePadding="5dip"
    android:gravity="center" />
```

Comment: This would have saved me a lot of time. I need to look more into these intricate details.